# Pass id user to view function

Tags: django, authentication, url, view

I try pass id by template to view but I have

> MultiValueDictKeyError at /accounts/profile/1

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'accounts:profile' request.user.id %}">{{request.user}}</a>

path('accounts/profile/<int:id>', views.profile, name="profile"),

def profile(request, id):
user = User.objects.get(id=int(request.POST[id]))
return user
```

Comment: What's the stacktrace say?

Answer (score 1):

Since the id is passed as URL parameter, you filter with:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def profile(request, id):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=id)
    # …
```

You can furthermore *not* `return user`, since that is a `User` object, not a `HttpResponse`, you thus need to return for example the result of rendering a template, etc.

Comment: Yes it's solve my problem, thank You :). How can I do it if I don't pass parameter in url and wan't get id from request?

Comment: @darek_82: then it is `pk=request.POST['id']` (or `request.GET` depending on the method).